# Check if Content Inside Youtube iFrame has Changed

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I have a `iframe` that initially does not contain a video. When the user presses a button, a Youtube video will load. To detect when the Youtube video has finished loading, I am using `on()` to detect when the DOM structure of the Youtube iframe has been modified. Currently I am not seeing the `Video Loaded` message in my console when the video has loaded. Is my logic incorrect?

```
<div id="button">BUTTON</div>

<div id="container">
    <iframe id="ytplayer" class="hide" type="text/html" width="840" height="470" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click( function() {
        $('#ytplayer').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/w7bccxRvxDc?rel=0&showinfo=0');
    });  
    $('#container').on('DOMNodeInserted', '#ytplayer', function() {
        console.log('Video Loaded');
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [YouTube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). It has support for a lot of events including when a video is loaded. The API is officially supported so you shouldn't need to support custom built code in the event Google changes something down the road.